# Auto-resize label + UitableView. Doesn't resize

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a table cell with 3 labels. Two of them has "lines: 0".

[image: cell view]

I set hugging and resistance priority like http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

And this works fine, but only if TableView located in "TabBarController". If i put same TableView to simple ViewController, Label1 not expanding.

Fine: 
[image: fine]

Wrong: 
[image: wrong]

I use one cell class and cell xib for both of tables. And one class as tables delegate/data source.

Tables delegate:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       var cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GraveTableViewCell") as? GraveTableViewCell
       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GraveTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? GraveTableViewCell
           cell?.configureCell(data[indexPath.row])
       }
       return cell! 
   }
```

Comment: Expanding or truncating? What's the expected result? To create new lines?

Comment: @DCGoD yes. Just like on the first picture

Comment: What often helps me with troubleshooting autolayout is to draw a border around each text label: `myLabel.layer.borderwidth = 0.5f;`

Comment: Could you also post all your constraints here?